# Access firebase from aws lambda (python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda

I have files in firebase that I want to storage in AWS S3. I found this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-access-firebase-from-aws-lambda-f7f494dd435a , but I can not figure out how do something like that with python.

Comment: have you checked out S3 examples here? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html